# Where is it written in the Zohar that the Yishmaelites must have Eretz Israel until Mashiah comes?

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, eretz-yisrael, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar

I remember reading a paper where it was written that the Yishmaelites should have Eretz Israel until the coming of Mashiah according to the Zohar. Is it true ? If it is the case, where is it written in the Zohar ?

Comment: it is not in the zohar, it is in Pirkei d'Rebbi Eliezer. Chapter 33 or 34 if memory serves.

Comment: I am pretty sure he told me it was in the Zohar but thanks

Comment: see also baal haturim on beginning of chumash parsha toldos

Comment: I didn't look up the sources inside, but look at the quotes on this page from 2 places in the Zohar and R' Chaim Vital: http://www.yesod-hatorah.org/torah.php?id=102&action=show_article&page=7&article_type=1

Comment: I still remember the story of the angel of Yishmael who negociate with Hashem the occupancy of Eretz Israel before the coming of Moshiach

Answer (score 5):

“In the future, the sons of Yishmael will return to the Holy Land when it was vacant from inhabitants for much time, and they will prevent Yisrael from returning to their land until that merit of the sons of Yishmael expires. At a certain time, the sons of Yishmael will be roused to wage brazen battles in the world. The sons of Edom will gather together and stage a war against them; one on the sea, one by land, and one close to Yerushalayim. At that time a nation will come from the end of the world onto Rome and make a battle with them for three months, and they will fall in their hands, until all the sons of Edom will gather from all corners of the world.” -Zohar Devarim 32a

“There is no exile more difficult for Yisrael than the Galus Yishmael” – Zohar Shemos 17a

Although it is not clear in the Zohar that the Galut Yishmael will end with the coming of Mashiach, the Baal HaTurim (23:18) wrote : "Next to this [verse it is written] ‘And These are the descendants of Yitzchak son of Avraham’, to tell us that when Yishmael falls in the end of days, then the son of David [Moshiach] will sprout forth, for he is the descendant of Yitzchak."

Source: http://www.yesod-hatorah.org/torah.php?id=102&action=show_article&page=7&article_type=1